# setting max_features to none in random forest

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, scikit-learn, cart

For sklearn's Random forest classification module, setting max_features to none takes into consideration all the n features for building each tree. In this case, how is it different from applying bagging to simple CART. Also isn't feature sampling the USP of random forest.

Comment: Actually it uses $\sqrt{N}$ ($N$ being number of all features) by default, see [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier)

Comment: sorry I meant "none"

Comment: Small correction: $m$ of the $p$ features are considered before each *node*, not before each tree, in Random Forest. Selecting a subset of predictors before each tree is the "random subspace" method, not Random Forest as typically understood/implemented.

Answer (score 1):

In bagging, the only parameter we tune is the number of trees. In Random Forest, we tune both the number of trees and the number of input variables $m 
\leq p$ considered for splitting each node. If $m = p$, we are bagging. Typically we choose $m \ll p$.

I assume by "USP" you mean "unique selling proposition?" If so, yes, the ability to consider a subset of features at each node is the main feature differentiating Random Forest from Bagging. The fact that one *could* set $m=p$ doesn't mean one *should*, and it doesn't invalidate the random feature subsetting as a "selling point" of Random Forest.

One typically uses $\sqrt{p}$ features, at least for classification problems.